# How to send sms in a language other than english

Tags: java, messaging, smpp

I'm using Logica SMPP api for sending sms. I'm able to send plain english messages with default data coding as "0" 
Now if I want to send sms in other language such as hindi or chinese, what are the different values I should set..

Should I create a UDH for the same ? 
wht data coding should I use? 
wht esm class should I set ? 
should I send the data as unicode?

Any suggestions on this will be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the API, I'd guess that [ShortMessage.setEncoding()](http://opensmpp.logica.com/CommonPart/Documentation/javadoc/library_1_3/com/logica/smpp/pdu/ShortMessage.html#setEncoding(java.lang.String)) is the relevant method here.